# How to render a value to string which is coming from sObjcet Long Text area in saleforce Apex Class

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, sobject, visuaforce

I have a sObject which has a Long Text Area field "Account_Id" which contains , "'Account Name'+Account.name"
but when i want to replace "Account.name" value from my Apex class than i am failed.
e.g.

```
Account = [select Name from Account where Id =: oId LIMIT 1] ;
Temp_c sTemp = [select Account_Id from Temp_c where Id =: sId LIMIT 1 ];
String sFinal = sTemp.Account_Id ;
```

sFinal should be like 'Account Name'+Ravi  (Account name is Ravi)

Please help me to get 'Account Name'+Ravi.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Given what you posted, this **may** be what you want...

```
Account a = [select Name from Account where Id =: oId LIMIT 1] ;
Temp_c sTemp = [select Account_Id from Temp_c where Id =: sId LIMIT 1 ];
String sFinal = 'Account Name ' + a.name;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Eric, but i just want to call String sFinal = sTemp.Account_Id; and it should be populate oAccount.name value to string when i'm trying to get this field to visualforce page than i'm getting "Account Name'+oAccount.name".                                                                             Account oAccount = [select Name from Account where Id =: oId LIMIT 1] ;
Temp_c sTemp = [select Account_Id from Temp_c where Id =: sId LIMIT 1 ];
String sFinal = sTemp.Account_Id ;

Comment: @kumargaurav - I have no idea what you are trying to do.